# Why is the ApproximateMessageCount property on an Azure Storage queue nullable?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

The title pretty much explains my question:

If there are no messages in the Storage Queue, why would it not just return 0, assuming we were able to get the queue reference and make a connection? Instead, it returns [`null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.approximatemessagecount.aspx).

Does it have to do with the fact that the message count is "approximate?" Curious, more than anything.

Comment: Really good question, that's something I've been looking to find out as well. I'm doing some digging now :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The approximate message count starts as `null` to indicate that it has not been initialized. After the first call to `FetchAttributes`, it is populated with the current value from the service. If there are no messages in the queue at this point then the value returned is zero.

Comment: Very interesting..Thanks for the heads up. Any particular reason that the call for `FetchAttributes` is necessary? Assuming it was an architecture decision?

Comment: We prefer the service calls to be explicit -- FetchAttributes sends a request on the wire and gets the queue metadata and approx. message count. We decided to avoid having such a (relatively) heavy operation on a property getter.

Comment: FetchAttributes does not always populate ApproimateMessageCount - i am still getting null. I have resorted to PeekMessage

Comment: @OzBob, how PeekMessage helps to return MessageCount? Are you looping through all of messages? What it there are millions of them?